# Generator freezing and needs to be interuppted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, scaffolding

I am trying to use this gem
https://github.com/AndyObtiva/ultra_light_wizard

When I run...

```
rails generate ultra_light_wizard:scaffold Project steps:basic_info,project_detail,file_uploads,preview attributes:name:string,description:text,start_date:date,delivery_date:date
```

The system freezes and I have to interrupt the process to do anything else. What is the best way to trouble shoot the issue? How can I run the command and get feedback on what the code is doing?

Comment: Its something on your system. I've quickly created a project with the gem you want to use and copy & pasted your command inside the terminal and scaffold generated everything. Are you using a new, empty fresh rails project for this? Which rail version are you using?

Comment: I created a new project.  Rails 5.2 and Ruby 2.6.1

Comment: @Prometheus,   I just wanted to see the pattern the generator created, would you mind pushing the app your created to a public git repo (GitHub)?

Comment: thank you for the link!

Comment: Got it, please delete.